# Flutter crash on iOS - io.flutter.1.io SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001b7a84964

Tags: ios, flutter, crash, crashlytics

My Firebase Crashlytics log some crashes only on iOS.

I have no idea when the error occurs and why.

Crash log:

```
Crashed: io.flutter.1.io
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1bf34 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 180
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1c318 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x150c0 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xf2f4 __FIRCLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x4660 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x138b4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xea6c FIRCLSExceptionRecord + 212
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xe700 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 592
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x12f58 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x15efc __cxa_rethrow + 148
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x17e8c objc_exception_rethrow + 44
11 CoreFoundation                 0x1f4a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 836
12 Flutter                        0x2f0f74 (Missing)
13 Flutter                        0x2f0788 (Missing)
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19a4 _pthread_start + 148
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xea0 thread_start + 8
```

It look like crash in background when I show "Device states" tab, right?
[image]
Flutter verrsion:

```
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (9 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```

flutter doctor -v:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale en-VN)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/TuanHwing/Desktop/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (9 weeks ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/TuanHwing/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone’s Tuấn (mobile) • f7f710fd822ab731ca493fa4f6293bdd4e1910bd • ios            • iOS 13.4.1 17E262
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve the problem?

Comment: I also facing this issue. How do you solve this issue. My flutter sdk is 3.1